# undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass , what causes this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi i am facing this error ,
completely new to rails so cant figure out what is causing it

my newBook.html.erb

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> new Book </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><%= @hello_message %></h1>
        <h1>Add new book</h1>
        <%= form_tag :action => 'create' %>
        <p>
            <label for="book_title">Title</label>:
            <%= text_field 'book', 'title' %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="book_price">Price</label>:
            <%= text_field 'book', 'price' %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="book_subject">Subject</label>:
            <%= collection_select(:book,:subject_id,@subjects,:id,:name) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="book_description">Description</label>
            <br/>
            <%= text_area 'book', 'description' %>
        </p>
        <%= submit_tag "Create" %>
        <%= end_form_tag %>
        <%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list'} %>
    </body>
</html>
```

my book model : book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :price,:description , :created_at 
  belongs_to :subject
  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_numericality_of :price, :message=>"Error Message"
end
```

my subject model : subject.rb

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :book

end
```

stack trace is :

```
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:364:in `options_from_collection_for_select'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:600:in `to_collection_select_tag'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:191:in `collection_select'
app/views/home/newBook.html.erb:19:in `_app_views_home_new_ook_html_erb__299261930_24178164'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
# -- snipped --
```

Comment: If this is RoR, why tag with `java`?

Comment: Paste your controller code.

Comment: @fge No [tag:java] tag in revision history. (?)

Comment: @gg_s I'm quite sure it was there, but ohwell, it's gone now ;)

Comment: @fge That's strange. Usually self-edits show up. Oh well, indeed.

Comment: @gg_s : yeah i removed the java tag , iadded it cause i usually answer java questions and was expecting the answer from java people , but then as per the suggestion i removed it

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
<%= collection_select(:book,:subject_id,@subjects,:id,:name) %>
```

Your `@subjects` object is undefined. You need in your controller action for this page something that sets the contents of that variable, for example:

```
@subjects = Subject.all
```

See the source for [options_from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-option_groups_from_collection_for_select) - first thing it does is a map call on the collection passed to it (in your case `@subjects`).

Comment: thanx , i knew it was coming null , but didnt knew how to populate in rails

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= collection_select(:book,:subject_id,Subject.all,:id,:name) %>
```

Comment: Best to build a collection in the **controller**, then pass it to the view in an instance variable, eg. `@subjects`. Calling a model directly from the view violates Rails' MVC pattern.

Comment: Looking at his code he is trying to create new book in which subject is the category. He can select the subject from the given collection of subjects. So I don't think my ans is wrong until and unless he needs specific subjects. If he needs specific subjects then he has to create a collection in controller side as @subjects and use that in collection_select.

Comment: @NikDP : you ans was sufficient , i only needed the push to populate the null field

Comment: @gg_s : yeah , i used the collection in the controller only

Comment: @NikDP I never said it was wrong, just that it isn't best practice. Calling a model from the view will work, as will most antipatterns, but one shouldn't make a habit of it.

Answer (score 0):

For people looking at this post and the answer isn't working for them;

I was trying to link the table "Locations" in the table "Departments".

The following code worked for me, having taking inspiration from the original answer;

```
# In app/views/departments/_form.html.erb:
...
    <p>
        <%= f.label :location %><br>
        <%= f.collection_select(:location,@locations,:id,:address) %>
    </p>    
...

# In app/controllers/departments_controller.rb;

  def new
    @locations = Location.all
  ....
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue. I had defined the object for the `new` method (which called the form page using `GET`) but had forgotten to define it for the `create` method (which accepted form values using `POST`), after defining it for both the `new` and the `create` issue got resolved.